# How to insert a space before the every sentence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My Input is:**

```
hello world one
hello world two
hello world three
```

I have tried so far:

```
  $('.insertSpace').click(function(event) {
    var textareaInput=$('.textareaInput').val();
    var myString = ' ' + textareaInput.split();
    $('.textareaInput').val(myString);
    //console.log(myString);
  });
```

It is working for just first sentence.I want to insert space in every sentence. Where is the fault in my code?

Its output should look like this:

```
 hello world one
 hello world two
 hello world three
```

Comment: *"My input is"* What is it? An array? A string with newlines? HTML with `<br>` elements?

Comment: Is this inside a `<textarea>`?

Comment: @j08691 yes `textarea`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have a text area where i will input those sentence and want to output as like as the question.Insert a space before every sentence of the given string.

Comment: Whats difference between your input and output....?

Comment: To insert a space before every line in the textarea.

Comment: @Hemakumar: It's **very subtle**, but there's a space at the beginning of each line of the output that isn't there in the input.

Comment: @Hemakumar difference is output inserted one space please look the output carefully.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myString = textareaInput.split("\n").map(function(str){ 
  return ' ' + str;
}).join("\n");
```

Comment: Its add a space only first sentence.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to split by `\n`. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple regex if you use the `m` modifier (which matches on a multi-line basis)

```js
function addSpaces() {
  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/^(.)/gm, ' $1');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">
hello world one
hello world two
hello world three
</textarea>
<button onclick="addSpaces()">Add Spaces</button>
```

However, if you also want to normalize spaces you can swap out that regex for this:

```
.replace(/^(?!\n)(\s*)(.)/gm, ' $2');
```

which will remove tabs, or pre-existing spaces and only add 1 space no matter how many times you run that function. It will leave new lines alone.

Comment: It's wordking.Cool !

Answer (score 1):

I think by "sentence" you mean **line**. If so, you can use `replace` with a regular expression to do that. Example:

```
var textareaInput = $('.textareaInput').val();
var myString = " " + textareaInput.replace(/(\r?\n)/g, "$1 ");
$('.textareaInput').val(myString);
```

Live copy:

```js
$('.insertSpace').click(function(event) {
  var textareaInput = $('.textareaInput').val();
  var myString = " " + textareaInput.replace(/(\r?\n)/g, "$1 ");
  $('.textareaInput').val(myString);
});
```

```html
<textarea class="textareaInput" cols="20" rows="5">
hello world one
hello world two
hello world three
</textarea>
<input type="button" class="insertSpace" value="Insert Space">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If the desired outcome is to move/indent the text to the right you can just use padding:

```css
.indent {
  /* Indent with as much you as like to */
  padding-left: 1rem; 
}
```

```html
<textarea class="indent" cols="20" rows="5">
  Some text
  Hello world
  Winter's coming
</textarea>
```